# Getting errors in expo about FontFamily antdesign

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am new to coding and I cant figure out a problem.
When I am opening a app in expo with the command

```
expo start -c
```

I am getting chinese symbols in my menu.
Then a red screen pops up with the following notificaton:

*console.error: fontFamily "AntDesign" is not a system font and has not been loaded through FontloadAsync*

I have googled the problem, and I have seen that people uploaded codes from 2 files, to get help.
App.js and package.json. So I have done it to.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { Root } from "native-base";
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import AppPreLoader from "./application/components/AppPreLoader";
import firebaseConfig from './application/utils/Firebase';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import GuestNavigation from './application/navigations/Guest';
import LoggedNavigation from './application/navigations/Logged';

console.disableYellowBox = true;

function cacheImages(images) {
  return images.map(image => {
    if (typeof image === 'string') {
      return Image.prefetch(image);
    } else {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }
  });
}

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLogged: false,
      loaded: false,
      isReady: false,
    }
  }

async _loadAssetsAsync() {
    const imageAssets = cacheImages([
      require('./assets/images/header.jpg'),
      require('./assets/images/logo.png'),
      require('./assets/images/logo_dark.png'),
      require('./assets/images/star.png'),
      require('./assets/images/avatar.png'),
      require('./assets/images/emptylist.png'),
      require('./assets/images/avatar.jpg'),
      require('./assets/images/nointernet.png'),
      require('./assets/images/contact.png'),
      require('./assets/images/address.png'),
      require('./assets/images/audience.png'),
      require('./assets/images/schedule.png'),
      require('./assets/images/phone.png'),
      require('./assets/images/website.png'),
      require('./assets/images/bookmarked.png'),
      require('./assets/images/checked.png'),
    ]);

    await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);
  }

  async componentDidMount () {

      await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
      'anticon': require('@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf'),
      'Entypo': require('@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Entypo.ttf'),
      'Ionicons': require('@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Ionicons.ttf'),
      'MaterialCommunityIcons': require('@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf'),
      'SimpleLineIcons': require('@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/SimpleLineIcons.ttf'),
      'FontAwesome': require('@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf')
    });
```

And package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "github:react-native-community/toolbar-android",
    "expo": "^38.0.9",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-facebook": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~8.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react-native-carousel": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-device-detection": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-form-validator": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.7.10",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-timeago": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.7.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^9.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.2.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I hope somebody can help me with this. It is my third night solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

you should load the font "AntDesign" with `expo-font`, as described in https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/#a-minimal-but-complete-working-example